# how to get attribute table from max(id) in sqllite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to check whether a record exists or not.

Here is what I've tried:

FormMain.java

```
public class FormMain extends FragmentActivity{
    public Button list,export,exit, resume;
    public String longitude,latitude,estate,block,ha;
    private Intent i; 
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    MySQLiteHelper db;
    private Tikos hamadetail;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        db.getReadableDatabase();

          dataList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //resume=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu)

         final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to resume census ?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Resume", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                          int ID = db.getHighestID(); 
                         //  String id1 = String.valueOf(id);
                           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "LastID: " + ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             List<Tikos> tikos = new LinkedList<Tikos>();
                                tikos= db.getLastIdData();


                                // looping through All data

                                for(Tikos temp_vg:tikos){
                                    temp_vg.getId();
                                    temp_vg.gettype();
                                    temp_vg.getdate();
                                    temp_vg.getestate();
                                    temp_vg.getblock();


                                    // creating new HashMap
                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                    map.put("id", String.valueOf(temp_vg.getId()));
                                    map.put("estate", temp_vg.getestate());
                                    map.put("block", temp_vg.getblock());
                                    map.put("ha", temp_vg.getha());

                                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    dataList.add(map);      
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Last estate: " + estate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Last block: " + block, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Last ha: " + ha, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent i = new Intent(FormMain.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra("id", id);
                                    i.putExtra("estate", estate);
                                    i.putExtra("block", block);
                                    i.putExtra("ha", ha);

                                    startActivity(i);   
                                    //finish();
                       }}
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("New Census", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            //dialog.cancel();
                          showInputNameDialog();


                            //finish();
                       }
                   });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

MySqliteHelper.Java

```
       public List<Tikos> getLastIdData() {
        List<Tikos> hama = new LinkedList<Tikos>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  estate,block,ha FROM " + TABLE_TIKOS+" ORDER BY MAX(id)";

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Tikos tikos1 = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tikos1 = new Tikos();

                tikos1.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                tikos1.setestate(cursor.getString(1));
                tikos1.setblock(cursor.getString(2));
                tikos1.setha(cursor.getString(3));


                // Add vgm 
                hama.add(tikos1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return hama;
    }

    public Cursor getAllDataLastId () {

      SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

      Cursor mCursor = db.query("SELECT estate,block, ha FROM tikos", 
              new String[] {KEY_ESTATE,KEY_BLOCK,KEY_HA}, 
              null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
      db.close();
          return mCursor;
  }

public int getHighestID() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM " + TABLE_TIKOS;
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int id = cur.getInt(0);
        cur.close();
        return id;
        }
```

logcat :

```
    07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "tyrrr"
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at com.titikkosong.MySQLiteHelper.getLastIdData(MySQLiteHelper.java:157)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at com.titikkosong.FormMain$1.onClick(FormMain.java:184)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
07-28 14:54:39.424: E/AndroidRuntime(4896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But it doesn't get it to the catch estate, block, and ha from max(id) to display the toast.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Is ID TABLE_TIKOS primary key?

Comment: yes.. it primary key and autoincrement

Comment: Don't change the question in a way that can invalidate existing answers. If the original question has been answered and you have a different problem, ask a new question. Also read the [tour]; and [how to accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Thank you @CL, when the the OP mentioned that there is another error I mistakenly believed that it was related to my answer so i took the bait! Having taken the bait, I had no choice but the edit the question so that both stack traces could be shown.

Comment: i still dont have an answer for my question..

Comment: you do have an answer to the original question you posted.

Comment: i meant, the eeror, when it catch the id values... but using the cursor get string value/.. so how do i solved it better?

Comment: the error come from                      tikos1.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

Comment: can any one help me.. i was succes for solved this , but the value is null, but in my sqlite i have a lots value .. please hel me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your full code? Because the following line should produce an exception but your don't seem to be catching it?

```
String query = "SELECT  estate,block,ha FROM " + TABLE_TIKOS+" ORDER BY MAX(id)";
```

This will result in a

> Query Error: misuse of aggregate: max() Unable to execute statement

To use ORDER BY MAX(id) in this manner your query would need a GROUP BY clause. Try something like this:

```
String query = "SELECT  estate,block,ha FROM " + TABLE_TIKOS
   +" GROUP BY some_column ORDER BY MAX(id)";
```

Comment: i replaced my query with your query, it seems not work properly.. still error on it. --> @E2C5

Comment: 07-22 10:52:35.855: E/AndroidRuntime(16374):  at com.titikkosong.MySQLiteHelper.getLastIdData(MySQLiteHelper.java:157)

Comment: sorry e4c5, your answer is still error when i used on my project

Comment: ok.. so what the clue for the error. your query was correct.. but my project still error

Comment: this the new link of new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649079/how-to-get-attribute-table-from-maxid-in-sqllite-android-part-2

Comment: great  you need to post your updated code (based on my suggestions and any other changes made) directly in that question or it's going to get a heap of down votes pretty quick

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT  MAX(id),estate,block,ha FROM " + TABLE_TIKOS + " where id=MAX(id)"
```